# Static javascript members

Tags: javascript, prototype

I have been using this for a while as a really nice workaround for how to declare static members for my objects but I really don't understand why they become static so I need somebody to explain to me the following behavior.

I have the following declarations:

```
// Primitive so nothing interesting here
Array.prototype.someMember = "My value is not static";
// Object containing a primitive, now this is the deal
Array.prototype.someOtherMember = {
    value: "My value is static"
};

Array.prototype.changeMember = function (newValue) {
    // Change the primitive value
    this.someMember = newValue;
    // Change the primitive value inside the object
    this.someOtherMember.value = newValue;
};
```

And if this is tested the following way:

```
var arr1 = [], arr2 = [], arr3 = [];
arr1.changeMember('I changed');
alert(arr1.someMember + ', ' + arr2.someMember + ', ' + arr3.someMember);
alert(arr1.someOtherMember.value + ', ' + arr2.someOtherMember.value + ', ' + arr3.someOtherMember.value);
```

The result is:

> I changed, My value is not static, My value is not static
>
> I changed, I changed, I changed

Now if I reassign the entire object in the `changeMember` method like this:

```
Array.prototype.changeMember = function (newValue) {
    // Change the primitive value
    this.someMember = newValue;
    // Change the object
    this.someOtherMember = { value: newValue };
};
```

Then `someOtherMember` is no longer static, but instead the first instance of Array gets its own. I don't understand the behavior because after all I am accessing `someOtherMember` through `this` in both cases, so I can't figure out why it's static in the first case and it's not static in the second.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no such thing as a static property in JS. What you're seeing is the normal behaviour of prototypal inheritance. The key concept is this: *Arrays, and indeed all objects, are sparse* An instance doesn't have a property unless it's explicitly assigned to that instance. as long as that doesn't happen, the prototype holds all properties:

*The first case*
Why are you seeing `I changed, My value is not static, My value is not static`? Simple: When arrays are instantiated, all instances will *appear* to have a property called `someMember`, but in fact, they don't. When you try to access `anArray.someMember` JS will first scan the instance for that property, if that instance doesn't have that property defined, JS will turn to the prototype and look for `someMember` there. In your snippet the `changeMember` method uses `this`, to refer to the instance that invokes the method, not `Object.getPrototypeOf(this).someMember`. The latter being the way to change the property on the prototype level. In short:

```
arr1.changeMember('I changed');
// is the same as doing:
arr1.someMember = 'I changed';
arr1.someOtherMember.value = 'I changed';
```

The assignment to `someMember` is a straightforward assignment, setting a property of an instance.

*The second case*
The second assignment is reassigning a property of an object, that is *referenced* by `Array.prototype.someOtherMember`. The *Reference* to the object literal doesn't change, only the object itself. Just as in any other language: when dealing with references, the object can change as much as it likes, the reference will remain the same (its value might change, but its memory address doesn't). 
When you redefine the `changeMember` method to reassign a new *Object literal* to a property, you're in essence creating the same situation as in case one: straightforward assignment of a new object to a property, that causes JS *not* to scan the prototype, but merely assign the property on an instance-level. You *could* use `Object.getPrototypeOf(this)` or (for older browsers) `this.prototype`:

```
Array.prototype.changeMember = function (val)
{
    this.someMember = 'I changed At instance level';
    Object.getPrototypeOf(this).someMember = 'Reassing prototype property to '+ val;
    Object.getPrototypeOf(this).someOtherMember = {value:val};//changes proto only
};
```

Having said that, if you want something like a static property, you're better of using `Object.defineProperty`:

```
Object.defineProperty(Array.prototype,'sortofStatic',{value:'I cannot be changed',writable:false,configurable:false});
```

More examples of this [can be found on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty)

Comment: So what is the difference between Object.defineProperty and Array.prototype.someOtherMember = {
    value: "My value is static"
};

Comment: @KonstantinD-Infragistics: using `Object.defineProperty`, you're not assigning an object literal, you're defining a property as read-only/rw, (non-)enumerable, ... just read the docs

Answer (score 0):

In someOtherMember one instance of Object is shared between all instances of Array.

In the first case you are changing the value of that object, so the value changes for all instances of Array.

In the second case you are changing an object itself. So the instance of an Array will contain another object that the others.

Comment: Not entirely correct: no array has the `someMember` property, JS gets that value directly from the prototype. When the `changeMember` function is called on an array instance, though, that instance is _augmented_ and gets its own `someMember` property, the other array instances still have no extra properties. The value of `someMember` isn't an object either, it's a constant

Answer (score 0):

The first case is well understood.

The second case (where `someOtherMember` isn't static member), you are overwritting the `someOtherMember` every time you call `changeMember` (deleting the static member `value`) therefore ceases to exist the static member.

Answer (score 0):

```
Array.prototype.someMember = "My value is not static";

// Here `someOtherMember` is simply a property which points to a memory location
// So initially it will point to the same memory location for all instances of `Array`
Array.prototype.someOtherMember = {
    value: "My value is static"
};

Array.prototype.changeMember = function (newValue) {

    this.someMember = newValue;

    // Here we change a value stored in the memory location pointed by `someOtherMember`
    // As all instances point to the same memory location this change will reflect in all instances
    this.someOtherMember.value = newValue;
};


Array.prototype.changeMember = function (newValue) {

    this.someMember = newValue;

    // Here for this particular instance we make `someOtherMember` point to a new memory location.
    // All instances will point to the old memory location until `changeMember` is invoked.
    this.someOtherMember = { value: newValue };
};
```