# JavaScript: Is Prototype Synonymous with Static?

Tags: javascript

I am teaching myself JavaScript coming from a OOP background. The book in which I am studying has made me think, "Wow, properties are almost the same as static methods or variables!" If this is the case I would love to implement them more to save some memory, but before I fall in love with them I want to make sure I'm using them correctly.

Is this the case? Is my logic wrong? I am adding some sample code below to use as context for my question. Hopefully it's not oversimplified:

```
function person(first, age){
    this.firstName = first;
    this.age = age;
}

person.prototype.sayHello = function(){
    return "hi my name is " + this.firstName + " and I am " + age + ".";
};
```

and thus the constructor function could be called the following way

```
var me = new person("Dan", 22);
```

Also, does this break encapsulation? The example above does not declare the variables in the class so they will be globally scoped. I understand the prototype would not be able to see `firstName` or `age` if they were declared `var firstName` and `var age`.

Do I have to pick one or the other? Can I not use my added prototypes and encapsulation?

Thanks ahead of time!

Comment: `prototype` is more like `class` rather than `static`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> Is Prototype Synonymous with Static?

No. Properties on the prototype are instance properties. If you attach a method to the prototype of a function then instances created from that function will inherit from that prototype. This means that all instances created from that function will share a single copy of that method on the prototype.

A 'static' property in JavaScript is best represented by a property directly on the constructor function itself:

```
function Person() {}
Person.count = 0;
```

Here, `count` is a 'static' property on the constructor. You could update that from e.g. within the constructor with `Person.count++`;

> The example above does not declare the variables in the class so they will be globally scoped

You don't have any variable declarations, only property assignments. Because the prototype method will be called in the context of an instance `this` will refer to that instance and therefore the prototype method has access to those instance properties.

The only thing that is 'global' in your example is the `person` constructor itself.

Comment: Thanks James, that was totally in depth and easy to follow. I really appreciate it!

Answer (score 2):

`JavaScript` is not really an object oriented language so you don't have real encapsulation. You have `closures`. Your methods can benefit from a closure and access a variable which is defined only in the `scope` of your person function, so you can call them `private`. You cannot however access these variables from a method defined on the `prototype` because that is no longer the same `scope`.

Also prototype is not synonymous with static as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12855561/static-javascript-members).

The main thing about the `prototype` is that objects and methods defined on the prototype provide the same instance of those objects and methods to each instance of the `object` produced with `new`. This means that if a method or object is defined on the `prototype` instead of through the function scope it will not have its own instance for each object instance created with `new`, which makes creating multiple members more efficient.

Comment: Saying javascript is not really an OO language because it doesn't have class is like saying C++ is not really an OO language because it doesn't have prototype or delegate. There's more than one type of OO. There are languages derived from Modula (class based) and languages derived form Self (prototype based)

Comment: I assume he meant to say: JavaScript is not like Java